# Cpanel error log [ client denied by server configuration ]

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, cpanel

This is the first time I visited my error log (in cpanel) and found this:

```
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.php3, referer: http://some_domain.com
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.php4, referer: http://some_domain.com
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.cgi, referer: http://some_domain.com
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.pl, referer: http://some_domain.com
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.shtml, referer: http://some_domain.com
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.html, referer: http://some_domain.com
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.htm, referer: http://some_domain.com

client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.php3
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.php4
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.cgi
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.pl
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.shtml
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.html
client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/public_html/myFolder/index.htm
```

Above in referer theres a domain and in second theres no referer.

Is some body trying to hack me? Or what is this..?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone's trying to enumerate your publicly accessible files? Not sure, Im not really familiar w/the format of CPanel's log file.

Can you get access to apache.log for the same time frame?

Comment: I accidentally cleared apache logs, I guess apache logs are placed as `error_log` in the directories where it is causing error

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue.

Try to put `DirectoryIndex index.php` in your .htaccess

Hope this will fix problem